# Performing query based on another query's result

Tags: mysql, subquery, query

First I have to run the query (1) using the `pagedetailid` number to get the `adblockid`. Then I have to put that `adblockid` into the other query (2) to get the result. What I would prefer is a single query.

1. ```
   select distinct Flyerid, adblockid, OriginalPagedetailid, Pagedetailid, 
   category, brand, [Sales Price], Size, Format, manufacturer
   from prdcnen where pagedetailid = '67197228466'
   ```
2. ```
   select distinct Flyerid, adblockid, OriginalPagedetailid, Pagedetailid, 
   category, brand,[Sales Price], Size, Format, manufacturer
   from prdcnen where Adblockid = 1521368536511158
   ```

How can I merge these two statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is an inner self join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       p1.Flyerid,
       p1.adblockid,
       p1.OriginalPagedetailid,
       p1.Pagedetailid,
       p1.category,
       p1.brand,
       p1.[Sales Price],
       p1.Size,
       p1.Format,
       p1.manufacturer
       FROM prdcnen p1
            INNER JOIN prdcnen p2
                       ON p2.Adblockid = p1.Adblockid
       WHERE p2.pagedetailid = '67197228466';
```

Answer (score 1):

In it's simplest form you can just replace the literal for adblockid with a query:

```
SELECT distinct Flyerid, adblockid, OriginalPagedetailid, Pagedetailid
     , category, brand,[Sales Price], Size, Format, manufacturer 
FROM prdcnen
WHERE adblockid = (select distinct adblockid
                   from prdcnen 
                   where pagedetailid = '67197228466')
```

Comment: There is no guarantee the `adblockid` is unique for each `pagedetailid`. I think you must use `LIMIT 1` instead of `DISTINCT`. Or `... WHERE adblockid = SOME (select ...`

Comment: @Akina, if it's not unique the question does not make sense. We would then have to choose an adblockid by some criteria, but none is given.

Comment: `DISTINCT` could still return multiple rows, so that is not a solution.  Also, `DISTINCT` is slower than simply `LIMIT 1`.